# Can electric field cause time dilation?

Tags: special-relativity, electric-fields, time-dilation

Is it possible that time pass slower or faster if an object is in high electric field just like gravity?

Answer (score 7):

No, electric and magnetic fields do not cause time dilation like gravity. There are various observations which show this. For example, notice that when light propagates through a region where there is already an electric field present, the propagation is not affected. Notice also that the equations of classical electromagnetism satisfy the requirements of special relativity, and in special relativity there is time dilation associated with motion but not with position.

However there is an indirect connection between electromagnetic fields and time dilation via gravity. Because an electromagnetic field carries energy, it also causes gravitation, so there is a contribution (typically small) to the local gravitational environment which is caused by any electromagnetic field that may be present. This non-zero gravitation will result in gravitational time dilation.

Comment: Any chance you could add a simple numerical example?

Comment: Near an electric charge the electromagnetic stress energy tensor can be as large as we want (well, classically, I dont know in QFT). Does that mean that gravity also grows unbounded?